# array in such a way that the first element is the first minimum and the second element is the first maximum and so on

Tags: javascript

> Blockquote
>   //This function returns the array in such a way that the first element is the first minimum and 
>   //the second element is the first maximum and so on.
>   // Sample Input: array=`[2,4,7,1,3,8,9]`. Expected Output : `[1,9,2,8,3,7,4]`

```
 enter code here
  function rupesh(arr){
  var n = arr.length;
  var max_ele = arr[n - 1]; 
  var min_ele = arr[0];
  var y=[] 
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {  
    if (i % 2 != 0) { 
     arr[i] = min_ele; 
      min_ele += 1;
      y.push(arr[i]) 
 }             
 else { 
    arr[i] =  max_ele;;
    max_ele -= 1;

  y.push(arr[i])
  } 
  }
        return y; 
          }
          var arr =rupesh ([2,4,7,1,3,8,9]) ; //output is [ 9, 2, 8, 3, 7, 4, 6 ]
         //should be output [1,9,2,8,3,7,4]

         console.log(arr)
   //function i rupesh with a parameter
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could sort a copy of the array and get either the first or last item until the array has no more item to get.

```js
const getMinMax = ([...a]) => {
    var result = [],
        next = 'shift';
        
    a.sort((a, b) => a - b);
    while (a.length) {
        result.push(a[next]());
        next = { shift: 'pop', pop: 'shift' }[next];
    }
    return result;
}

var array = [2, 4, 7, 1, 3, 8, 9],
    result = getMinMax(array);

console.log(result);
```